# Can branch and bound be defined as a method to search a non-convex solution space which uses linear programming models to guide the search?

Tags: branch-and-bound

Can branch and bound be defined as a method to search a non-convex solution space which uses linear programming models(and solving them) to guide the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite branch and bound is a more general algorithm that also applies to non-linear models. The important thing is that you can calculate a "relaxation" which is guaranteed to be a bound on the objective. If one restricts oneself to MILP, then yes, your suggests describes branch and bound for MILP correctly. For non-linear models there exist different solutions to get lower bounds such as generic Interval Arithmetic or more other methods to find global minima of relaxations.

Comment: Branch-and-bound implies neither a model nor a relaxation, just branching and bounding

Comment: I am curious, how do you derive a bound without some kind of relaxation? Especially if one allows integer valued variables in the model.

Comment: For example, for the graph coloring problem, a bound can be obtained by computing a clique. It would be unusual to call the maximum clique problem a relaxation of the graph coloring problem